# Borrowing from an owned box inside a tuple in Rust

Tags: rust, borrowing

The main goal is to access an owned box that is inside a tuple, e.g. the string from the `(String, i32)` in the code below.

My first intention was to use a `let` binding to borrow from the owned box. Borrowing works for the non-tuple case (1), but not when a tuple is involved (2).

Is my intention wrong, and if so, is there another idiomatic way to access the string?

Example code:

```
fn main() {
    // 1. Normal borrowing
    let s: String = "blub".to_string();
    let sr: &str = &s; // this works

    // 2. Borrowing from a tuple
    let st = ("blub".to_string(), 1);
    let (st_r, i): (&str, i32) = st; // error: mismatched types:

    println!( "{} {} {} {}", s, sr, st_r, i);
}
```

The compiler error is:

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `(&str, i32)`,
    found `(collections::string::String, _)`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ref` keyword is used to bind by reference.

```
let (ref st_r, i) = st;
```

Comment: Note that when you do that, you get `st_r: &~str`, not `st_r: &str`.  That's why `as_slice()` is needed anyway. This can be checked very easily: `println!("{}", st_r as int);` leads to `error: non-scalar cast: &~str as int`

Comment: The `as_slice()` call is definitely an important part of the answer. In my code I eventually used the equivalent if `let (ref st_r,i)=st; let st_r = st_r.as_slice()`. Mentioning the `int` two additional times in the matching approach felt a bit redundant.

Answer (score 2):

The most direct way, I believe, is matching:

```
let st = (~"blub", 1i);
let (st_r, i) = match st {
    (ref s, i) => (s.as_slice(), i)
};
println!("{} {}", st_r, i);
```

Note that I used `ref s` and `s.as_slice()` instead of `s` or `&*s` for two reasons. First, `&*s` is not allowed due to current special status of `~str` type. It seems that it will be possible when DST change lands. Second, I used `ref s` because otherwise first tuple component is moved into `s`, and it wouldn't be possible to return a reference to it from inside of `match` body at all - it will be destroyed when `match` ends.

There is no such problem with `i` because `int` is implicitly copyable.

Comment: You probably should update this question for Rust 1.0 and up.

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about a single value of the tuple, you can also use the numeric accessors (`.0`, `.1`, and so on). These can have the reference operator `&` applied to them:

```
let st = ("blub".to_string(), 1);
let st_r = &st.0;
```